# What is the advantage on road bikes where the seat stay merges into the upper part of the seat tube, but well below the top tube

Tags: road-bike, frames, framebuilding

For a few years now, you see more and more road bike manufacturers building this new frame shape. What is the advantage of this geometry?

[image]

Comment: This feature is called *dropped seatstays*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It offers both improved comfort (less resistance to vertical forces) and improved aerodynamics.

Road.cc have a large article discussing this subject: https://road.cc/content/feature/what-are-dropped-seatstays-good-267053

Comment: Thank you very much Andy! But to be honest, the old classic geometry looks better for me ;-)

Comment: Besides (subjective) aesthetics, are there actually any other downsides to dropped seatsays?

Comment: @DoNuT Theoretically, it's a structurally inferior design since the seatstays aren't directly transferring force into the top tube. In practice though, you don't want frame tubes to be too thin (low impact strength), so the inefficiency isn't really a problem. I could foresee complications in mounting some fenders and racks, but well-designed parts should be able to adjust.

Comment: It may not be "structurally inferior." As the linked article mentions, the resulting smaller triangle formed by dropping the seat stays results in a more laterally stiff design. Smaller triangle= stiffer frame. Then there's the improved aerodynamics of the dropped stays. Wind resistance above a certain, fairly low threshold is the chief force that requires exponentially more power to defeat. At the risk of quibbling, if the material and it's design can take the forces exerted upon it without permanent deformation or breakage, it can't be described as structurally inferior.